# How to use InsertOnly method in OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Following this example, how is the correspondent for the method InsertOnly?

```
var updated = await dbCon.UpdateOnlyAsync(timesheet,
onlyFields: 
    x =>
        new
        {
            x.LogInTime,
            x.LogOffTime,
            x.IsFlaggedByLeader,
            x.LeaderComment,
            x.IsModified
        },
@where: x => x.Id == timesheet.Id) > 0;
```

> I couldn't find an example on Internet and in the Ormlite
>   documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some examples in [ApiSqlServerTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/203d4bc71e833681962650f9f2adf737c60685df/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs#L242-L246), e.g:

```
db.InsertOnly(() => new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 });

db.InsertOnly(new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 }, 
    p => new { p.FirstName, p.Age });

db.InsertOnly(new Poco { Age = 27 }, p => p.Age);

db.InsertOnly(new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 }, 
    new[] { "FirstName", "Age" });
```

and async versions in [ApiSqlServerTestsAsync](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/203d4bc71e833681962650f9f2adf737c60685df/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLiteV45.Tests/ApiSqlServerTestsAsync.cs#L235-L239), e.g:

```
await db.InsertOnlyAsync(() => new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 });

await db.InsertOnlyAsync(new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 }, 
    p => new { p.FirstName, p.Age });

await db.InsertOnlyAsync(new Poco { Age = 27 }, p => p.Age);

await db.InsertOnlyAsync(new Poco { FirstName = "Amy", Age = 27 }, 
    new[] { "FirstName", "Age" });
```

Comment: Yes, I just found. Thanks @mythz